# Average calculating of consecutive list elements in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, average

I am trying to write a function in OCaml that will calculate the average of consecutive elements in a list. For example with `[1; 2; 3; 4]` it should output `[1; 2; 3]`. It should take `(1 + 2) / 2` and give `1` then take `(2 + 3) / 2` and give `2` and so on.
The code I wrote, however, only returns `[1; 2]`:

```
let rec average2 xs = match xs with
|[] -> []
|x :: [] -> [x]
|x :: x' :: xs -> if xs = [] then [(x + x') / 2] else [(x + x') / 2] @ (average2 xs)
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing `x :: y :: l` in a match, you're effectively taking out the elements of the list permanently.
So if you want to do an operation on pairs of elements, you need to put one back in.

Example:

You have a list of `[1;2;3;4]`

You want to operate on 1 and 2, in your match it will interpret as:

```
1 :: 2 :: [3;4]
```

If you continue without adding an element in, the next statement would be:

```
3 :: 4 :: []
```

which is not what you want.

To correct this, in your recurice call you need to do `(average2 (x'::xs)` and not just `(average2 xs)` because `xs` is the rest of the list after taking the elements out.

Answer (score 1):

OCaml allows to bind a pattern `p` to a variable `v` using `p as v` ([*alias patterns*](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html#hevea_manual.kwd7)):

```
let rec average2 = function
| x :: (y :: _ as tail) -> (x + y) / 2 :: (average2 tail)
| _ -> []
```

Above, `y :: _ as tail` destructures a list named `tail` as a non-empty list headed by `y` and having an arbitrary tail `_`, the value of which we don't care about. 
Note that I also simplified your function so that you don't check whether `_` is empty or not: recursion handles this for you here.
Also, when you have zero or one element in the list, you should return an empty list.

```
# average2 [ 10; 20; 30; 40];;
- : int list = [15; 25; 35]
```